# .upcase every other array item RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

First post.

The code below works, sorting my answers alphabetically, but I am having a hard time adding a conditional to my program.

I believe I need to include an if/else statement so that every other answer is in caps.

ie:  names = ["Bob", "Joe", "Bill", "Fred"]
desired output  =

BILL

bob

FRED

joe

### The code:

```
names = []

4.times do
  puts "Please enter your amigo's names:"
  names << gets.chomp
end

SortNames = names.sort

SortNames.each do |name|
  puts "There once was a person named " + name + "."
end
```

---

Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
formatted = []
names.each_slice(2) do |odd, even|
  formatted << odd.upcase
  formatted << even.downcase if even
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names.sort.each_with_index do |name, index|
  formatted_name = index.odd? ? name : name.upcase
  puts "There once was a person named #{formatted_name}."
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this! Do you happen to know of a way to do this without the with_index method?

Comment: Watcha got against the ```with_index``` method? :)

Comment: haha nothing actually, my instructor would like us to not use it for this excercise. All the examples I found online refer to the with_index method, which honestly seems more elegant and efficient. Do you know of another way to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 0):

I like this:

```
["Bob", "Joe", "Bill", "Fred"].sort.each_with_index.map{|x,n| n.even? ? x.downcase : x.upcase}
```

or

```
names = ["Bob", "Joe", "Bill", "Fred"]
puts names.sort.each_with_index.map{|x,n| n.even? ? x.downcase : x.upcase}
```

output:

```
bill
BOB
fred
JOE
```

Not sure if you want to sort it first or not. Removing `.sort` that will give you the original order.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this! Do you happen to know of a way to do this without the with_index method?